# Setting environment variables in kubernetes manifest using "kubectl set env"

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-deployment

I am trying to update a helm-deployed deployment so that it uses a secret stored as a k8s secret resource.  This *must* be set as the STORAGE_PASSWORD environment variable in my pod.

In my case, the secret is in secrets/redis and the data item is redis-password:

```
$ kubectl get secret/redis -oyaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  redis-password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: redis
type: Opaque
```

I have tried:

```
$ kubectl set env --from secret/redis deployment/gateway --keys=redis-password
Warning: key redis-password transferred to REDIS_PASSWORD
deployment.apps/gateway env updated
```

When I look in my updated deployment manifest, I see the variable has been added but (as suggested) the variable has been set to REDIS_PASSWORD:

```
        - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              key: redis-password
              name: redis
```

I have also tried `kubectl patch` with a `replace` operation, but I can't get the syntax correct to have the secret inserted.

How do I change the name of the environment variable to STORAGE_PASSWORD?

Comment: If Helm is managing the Kubernetes manifests, I'd try to make this change inside your Helm chart – I would _not_ use `kubectl set` or `kubectl edit` on something Helm is managing, since the results will be somewhat unpredictable if you `helm upgrade` the chart.  Can you make this change in the `templates/deployment.yaml` file instead, maybe gated on some specific `{{ if .Values... }}` setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a deployment that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: example
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: alpinelinux/darkhttpd
          name: darkhttpd
          args:
            - --port
            - "9991"
          ports:
            - name: http
              protocol: TCP
              containerPort: 9991
          env:
            - name: EXAMPLE_VAR
              value: example value
```

The syntax for patching in your secret would look like:

```
kubectl patch deploy/example --patch='
  {
    "spec": {
      "template": {
        "spec": {
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "darkhttpd",
              "env": [
                {
                  "name": "STORAGE_PASSWORD",
                  "valueFrom": {
                    "secretKeyRef": {
                      "name": "redis",
                      "key": "redis-password"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
'
```

Or using a JSONPatch style patch:

```
kubectl patch --type json deploy/example --patch='
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/env/-",
    "value": {
      "name": "STORAGE_PASSWORD",
      "valueFrom": {
        "secretKeyRef": {
          "name": "redis",
          "key": "redis-password"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
'
```

Neither one is especially pretty because you're adding a complex nested structure to an existing complex nested structure.

Comment: Works!  The first makes more sense to me (and worked perfectly).  One question, though... in the JSONPatch, I'm assuming that the '.../containers/0/...' is a reference to container "0" in a potentially longer list.  Is this correct?  Either way, I'd tried 100 variations of patch and 'set env' and was unable to get this to work.

Comment: `.../containers/0/` means "the first item in the list `.../containers`".

Answer (score 1):

you may also update resources with `kubectl edit`:

```
kubectl edit deployment gateway
```

then edit the yaml file

```
    # - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
    - name: STORAGE_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: redis-password
          name: redis
```

FYI: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#kubectl-edit

Comment: Sorry -- I wasn't specific enough in my question.  Yes, I was able to do it with edit, but I was trying to automate the process in a script.  Still, this answer is correct.